# How to draw a square composed of four triangles ? ( libgdx )

Tags: java, libgdx, shapes

I've a case in which I need to draw square composed of four triangles like in the photo bellow :

[image]

The triangles parameters are stored in the JDBC , I know how to draw shapes in Libgdx but this kind of shape seems a bit tricky to me , any help or any idea on how to do this would be greatly appreciated . ( I'm not asking to write the code for me )

Comment: One solution would be to draw the "squares" of images (the black image on top, the red image on right, the yellow/blue image on left, and the blue/white image on bottom), and then rotate each 45 degrees to compose  composite image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is a simple example, I could not eh It tests, because I have no access to libgdx now, but as an idea I think, you can help.

```
void draw(float x, float y, float width, float height, Color color) {


    if (idx==verts.length)
        flush();

    //assuming (0, 0) is lower left, and Y is up

    //bottom left vertex
    verts[idx++] = x;           //Position(x, y) 
    verts[idx++] = y;
    verts[idx++] = color.r;             //Color(r, g, b, a)
    verts[idx++] = color.g;
    verts[idx++] = color.b;
    verts[idx++] = color.a;

    //top left vertex
    verts[idx++] = x;           //Position(x, y) 
    verts[idx++] = y + height;
    verts[idx++] = color.r;             //Color(r, g, b, a)
    verts[idx++] = color.g;
    verts[idx++] = color.b;
    verts[idx++] = color.a;

    //bottom right vertex
    verts[idx++] = x + (width / 2);         //Position(x, y) 
    verts[idx++] = y + (height / 2);
    verts[idx++] = color.r;             //Color(r, g, b, a)
    verts[idx++] = color.g;
    verts[idx++] = color.b;
    verts[idx++] = color.a;
            //2
            //|\
            //| \ 3
            //| /
            //|/
            //1

    //
    verts[idx++] = x + width;       //Position(x, y) 
    verts[idx++] = y + height;
    verts[idx++] = color.r;             //Color(r, g, b, a)
    verts[idx++] = color.g;
    verts[idx++] = color.b;
    verts[idx++] = color.a;

    //
    verts[idx++] = x;           //Position(x, y) 
    verts[idx++] = y + height;
    verts[idx++] = color.r;             //Color(r, g, b, a)
    verts[idx++] = color.g;
    verts[idx++] = color.b;
    verts[idx++] = color.a;

    //
    verts[idx++] = x + (width / 2);         //Position(x, y) 
    verts[idx++] = y + (height / 2);
    verts[idx++] = color.r;             //Color(r, g, b, a)
    verts[idx++] = color.g;
    verts[idx++] = color.b;
    verts[idx++] = color.a;

            //2_____1
            // \   /
            //  \ /
            //   3
            //
            //

            //
    verts[idx++] = x + width;       //Position(x, y) 
    verts[idx++] = y;
    verts[idx++] = color.r;             //Color(r, g, b, a)
    verts[idx++] = color.g;
    verts[idx++] = color.b;
    verts[idx++] = color.a;

    //
    verts[idx++] = x + width;       //Position(x, y) 
    verts[idx++] = y + height;
    verts[idx++] = color.r;             //Color(r, g, b, a)
    verts[idx++] = color.g;
    verts[idx++] = color.b;
    verts[idx++] = color.a;

    //
    verts[idx++] = x + (width / 2);         //Position(x, y) 
    verts[idx++] = y + (height / 2);
    verts[idx++] = color.r;             //Color(r, g, b, a)
    verts[idx++] = color.g;
    verts[idx++] = color.b;
    verts[idx++] = color.a;

            //      2
            //     /|
            //   3/ |
            //    \ |
            //     \|
            //      1

    //
    verts[idx++] = x;                   //Position(x, y) 
    verts[idx++] = y;
    verts[idx++] = color.r;             //Color(r, g, b, a)
    verts[idx++] = color.g;
    verts[idx++] = color.b;
    verts[idx++] = color.a;

    //
    verts[idx++] = x + width;       //Position(x, y) 
    verts[idx++] = y;
    verts[idx++] = color.r;             //Color(r, g, b, a)
    verts[idx++] = color.g;
    verts[idx++] = color.b;
    verts[idx++] = color.a;

    //
    verts[idx++] = x + (width / 2);         //Position(x, y) 
    verts[idx++] = y + (height / 2);
    verts[idx++] = color.r;             //Color(r, g, b, a)
    verts[idx++] = color.g;
    verts[idx++] = color.b;
    verts[idx++] = color.a;

            //   3
            //  /\
            // /__\
            // 1  2 
    flush();
}
```

**NOTE:** When I wrote, the answer was not remembered in shape, that this example is for a mesh of libgdx.

Only you would have to adapt the code to draw a texture in each triangle, or color that your look.

If you need, some more code to make it work, comment on, and if I can I say you.

and if not, it work for you, comments, and I will delete

Answer (score 1):

Use four calls to ShapeRenderer.triangle()

Example (untested)...

```
// Assumes you set a shapes roperty in your create method
// e.g. this.shapes = new ShapeRenderer();

public void square(float x, float y, float width, float height, Color color) {

    float centerX = width / 2;
    float centerY = height / 2;
    float x2 = x + width;
    float y2 = y + height;

    shapes.begin(ShapeRenderer.ShapeType.Filled);
    shapes.triangle(x, y, centerX, centerY, x2, y, color, color, color);
    shapes.triangle(x2, y, centerX, centerY, x2, y2, color, color, color);
    shapes.triangle(x2, y2, centerX, centerY, x, y2, color, color, color);
    shapes.triangle(x, y2, centerX, centerY, x, y, color, color, color);
}
```

I hope this helps